# What is the most semantically correct structure of a blog page using HTML5 tags?

Tags: blog, html5, markup

I'd like to *grok* the ultimate nature of `<aside>`, `<section>`, `<article>`.

What is the best, most semantically correct structure of a blog page using HTML5 tags?

Should I put the sidebar inside an `<aside>`? Or does this rather belong into a `<section>` (as `<aside>` should be used for advertisements, short quotes and such)?

How should I present the main feature, the blog post? How do I use `<article>` correctly?

How should I mark-up the article tags?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use `<article>` for Blog posts. Mark Pilgrim has a really good [explanation](http://diveintohtml5.org/semantics.html#new-elementsBlockquote) of how to use each tag. He also explains how to mark-up the `article` just below the list of definitions on his site. This is a fantastic book for learning HTML 5 and CSS.

"The article element represents a component of a page that consists of a self-contained composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is intended to be independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication."

`Aside` is for "tangentially related" elements and the `section` represents "represents a generic document or application section."

Comment: Link toL http://diveintohtml5.org/semantics.html#new-elementsBlockquote is broken

Answer (score 2):

For `<aside>`, think of that like the theatrical aside: the story is put on hold to explain something to the audience, veering off on a tangent for a short bit before returning to the main focus. E.g.:

```
<article>
     <p>A horse walks into a bar.</p>
     <p>The bartender says, "Why the long face?"</p>
     <aside>Not because it was sad, horses just have long faces.</aside>
</article>
```

Terrible example, but a valid one.  Chances are it will be useful for things like pull-quotes and other article-relevant tangents, but as a **purely semantic** tag, advertisements generally don't belong.

A keyword-driven ad system won't care about semantically fitting your content, it's more interested in matching demographics. If your `<article>` is only about PHP, and it pulls ads related to Python/Perl/Java (it will, at some point), your `<aside>` just lost it's meaning.  You're better off putting those elsewhere on the page.

Comment: +1 for putting a smile on my face and answering a question of my own that I had.